# Finding mysql error occured location

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this mysql error

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'AND (
>   XYZField = 5)' at line 1 "

This error doesnt give information about mysql error occured location , i mean filename, function and line number.Is there any way to retrieve this info?

Comment: how you get this error, did you use adodb or something?

Comment: This error came in a PHP script

Comment: It is impossible with mysql alone what language you are using?

Comment: What's the underlying language you're using and does it support exceptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do. You have to create you own error handler. This will require a extra code from your side.

For an example:-

Assuming you are using `mysql_` family function and PHP

When you invoke any query you have to handle these mysql errors and can pass some of the variable containing function, file name info to customize errors.

Look at the [debug-backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) function of PHP this will give you what you needed. The current line number, file name function name, class name.

You can get data from this function and pass them into the trigger_error along with mysql_error() function

```
  mysql_query('SELECT ....') or trigger_error(mysql_error().' in the file 
'.$filename.' with function'.$function_name)
```

This is just a direction you can do even better from this.

**EDIT AFTER THE OP COMMENT**

You have customized database class

```
function db_error($query, mysql_errno(), mysql_error())
{
   $info=debug_backtrace();
   //This return array containing file name, line number function name etc
   //your rest code to display errors
}
```

Comment: Exactly. PHP and MySQL can work together but they are completely different technologies. The MySQL server knows nothing about your PHP code!

Comment: You are right i am using customized database class.                 In that  $result = mysql_query($query, $this->db) or $this->db_error($query, mysql_errno(), mysql_error()); But this gives error  and error number. But not error location. Using Xdebug i am able to trace called function/code but is there any other way, other than Xdebug.

Comment: @Álvaro: True, The answer has nothing to do with `mysql`. It is describing that after execution of query mysql return error to PHP through the PHP function and we are going to customize that message in PHP

Comment: @Harry: read the answer again it is giving everything you needs

Comment: @Harry:Your welcome If it helped consider to accept the answer by clicking right arrow

Answer (score 0):

Search in your PHP code for `XYZField` and check what is added before.