# How to show error line using mysqli_error()?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Hi I am using the below code, it says for example:

**Error message:** Unknown column '`ladderID`' in '`where clause`'
But does not say what file and what line it is producing the error from?

```
printf("Error message: %s\n", mysqli_error($this->connection))
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Example http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/5511773/1612250](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5511773/1612250) Check this, maybe it helps you

Comment: Here is the right way: [Mysqli update throwing Call to a member function bind_param() error](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15447204/285587)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you writing an update statement:
        UPDATE ladders SET Description ='Green ladder' WHERE ladderID = 50;
printf has nothing to do with files.
printf means outputting a string in a certain format.
mysqli is being used to access data from a database.